# redirect_uri_mismatch with Google Sign-In for server-side apps

Tags: node.js, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have a problem with my Google Sign in.
I follow the steps on [Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)
After all this step, i have this html file that run on a server :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
        <!-- BEGIN Pre-requisites -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js?onload=start" async defer></script>
        <!-- END Pre-requisites -->
        <script>
            function start() {
                gapi.load('auth2', function() {
                    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="googleBtn">Connect</button>
        <script>
            $('#googleBtn').click(function() {
                auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(googleCallback);
            });
        </script>
        <script>
            function googleCallback(authResult) {
                if (authResult['code']) {
                    console.log(authResult);
                } else {
                    console.log(authResult);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This first part work perfectly (I think), when I click on button, a window popup, I select an account and I get a code. So now, I want to get email and profile, so I make this request in nodejs to exchange the code with an access token.

```
var form = {
    code: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: 'CLIENT',
    grant_type:'authorization_code'
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

request({
    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: formData,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, rep, body) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(rep.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
  });
```

But in response, I have this

```
{
 "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
 "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

And I don't understand why, because I don't use any redirect_uri in primary request in html file. I have try some cases like add redirect_uri on Console API and in request, but I have the same result...

Can you help me ?

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: not realy, I've changed for this method (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), because I haven't found any solution to this issue

Answer (score 9):

From a client side `auth2.grantOfflineAccess` process, to get accessToken on server, you have to pass `redirect_uri=postmessage` in request params.

From your example :

```
var form = {
  code: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  client_id: 'CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: 'CLIENT',
  grant_type:'authorization_code',
  redirect_uri: 'postmessage' // the line to add
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Just curious, how did you find out the `redirect_uri` should be "postmessage"?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry.. after a lot of search, reverse, etc. ;)

Comment: You saved my deadline, thank you ! I'm still looking for the doc at Google. Even the server side tutorial *doesn't talk about it !* https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

Comment: Their documentation is woeful, as are their support team. Thanks so much @Doubidou

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your callback url to Google via console.developer.google.com

So you need to follow this steps for define the callback URL:

1. Go to console.developer.google.com
2. Select your project.
3. Click 'Credentials' on the left menu.
4. Click your client on the 'OAuth 2.0 client IDs' list.
5. Add your callback url to 'Authorized redirect URIs' list.

And done.

Comment: I have already do this before, but finally I don't use this method ([Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)), but Thanks

Comment: is it fixed ? I'm having same problem

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I have registered the redirects in google.  Was there a solution?